# On the definition of locally integrable functions on an abstract measure space.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Recently I've been able to find a very cheap copy of the nice monograph [1], where I can find (chapter 10, §1, p. 163) the following general definition of *Locally integrable function* (respect to a measure $\mu$)

> Let $\mathscr C$ be a *clan* of subsets of $T$, $E$ a Banach space and $\mu$ a *positive measure* on $\mathscr C$.
> **Definition 1**. *A function* $\boldsymbol f$ *defined on $T$ with values in $E$ or in $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is said to be locally integrable with respect to $\mu$, or locally $\mu$-integrable, if for every $A\in\mathscr{C}$ the set function ${\boldsymbol f}\varphi_A$ is $\mu$-integrable.*

In the above definition

- A *clan* $\mathscr C$ ([1], chapter 1, §1, p.1, also called a *ring of sets* as in [2], chapter I, §4, p. 19) is a family of subsets of $T$ (i.e. $\mathscr C\subset\mathscr P(T)$) characterized by the following two properties

  1. $A\setminus B\in\mathscr{C}$ for all $A, B\in \mathscr{C}$.
  2. $A\cup B\in\mathscr{C}$ for all $A, B\in \mathscr{C}$.
- $\varphi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A\in \mathscr C$, i.e. the function
  $$
  \varphi_A (x)=
  \begin{cases}
  1 & x\in A\\
  0 & x\notin A
  \end{cases} \qquad A\in\mathscr C.
  $$

**Question**. How can I show that, when $T$ is a finite dimensional vector space, or more generally a topological vector space, **definition 1** above reduces to the standard one(s) as given for example in the Wikipedia entry "[Locally integrable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function)"?

**What I've tried**. Basing on the above definition of a clan/ring of sets, I tried to see if  the properties of these families of sets imply their compactness when defined on a topological space, but I failed. Precisely, I was not able to prove that for any given open covering $\mathscr{B}$ of the sets $A\in\mathscr{C}$ it is possible to select one $\mathscr{B}_f\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ containing finitely many members.

**Context**. Years ago I contributed a lot to [the said Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function): jointly with other contributors we were able to describe quite accurately the case of locally integrable functions on a finite dimensional measurable space $T$, i.e. $T=\Bbb R^n$, $n\ge1$. Moreover, as stated in the entry itself, we also stated that the extension of the concept when $T$ is a general topological space does not involve any true difficulty, since the meaning of compactness of a set $A\subset T$ is obvious as in the finite dimensional case. Nevertheless I know that *the concept of a locally integrable function makes sense also when $T$ is simply an abstract set* without any other assumptions: since a description of this extension is also asked by [an anonymous commenter in the entry talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Locally_integrable_function),  I aim to complete the entry in that sense.

**References**

[1] Nicolae Dinculeanu, *Vector measures* (English), Hochschulbücher für Mathematik. 64, Berlin: VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften, pp. X+432 (1966), [MR206189](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=206189), [Zbl 0142.10502](https://zbmath.org/0142.10502). (Also published by Pergamon Press in 1967 as volume 95 of their "International Series of Monographs in Pure and Applied Mathematics").

[2] Paul R. Halmos, *Measure theory*, 2nd printing, (English)
Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 18, New York-Heidelberg-Berlin: Springer-Verlag, pp. XI+304 (1974), [MR0033869](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=33869), [Zbl 0283.28001](https://zbmath.org/0283.28001).

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, the definition should only reduce for a suitable choice of ring of sets. For example, on $\mathbb{R}^d$, a perfectly good ring of sets is $\{\mathbb{R}^d, \emptyset\}$ from which you recover the definition of integrability rather than local integrability.

Comment: @RhysSteele thus this kind of locality is meant in a very wide sense, implying that there is not a direct generalization to the case of $\Bbb R^n$, but instead a variety of generalizations of which the standard one is just a case? This is intriguing, I'd like to work it out.

Comment: There is sort of a way to make an abstract measure space into a dense subset of a locally compact space with a Radon measure (not the Kakutani way, *cf*. [this article](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01473893) in German and [this article](https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.1480) in French). 

Maybe it is possible to link local integrability in the sense introduced by Dinculeanu and local integrability on the larger locally compact space in the usual sense.

Comment: @P.P.Tuong thank you so much for the references.

Comment: Relatively compact sets seem to form clan on locally compact space. And in usual definition one can replace compact sets with relatively compact sets. Or did I misinterpret question?

Comment: @dsh thank you for sharing your insight, and no, you did not misinterpret the question. So let me recall to my self your point: 
* first, relatively compact sets on a topological space form a clan. 
* Second, from any (relatively) open cover of a relatively compact set, a finite (relatively) open cover can be extracted. 
* Third, if the set $E$ respect to which relative compactness is defined is chosen to be the whole topological space, we are done. 
Did I understand correctly your observation?

Comment: @dsh Moreover if I guessed correctly the route from your observation and you are willing to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I thought one needs only to convert set of compact sets to equivalent clan (needed to fix set difference). Observation is that *measurable* rel.compact set is exactly set which is *measurable subset of a compact.*  All compacts in common case are measurable (and even integrable). Agree with first and third point. The second point is not needed. Integrability wrt all compact sets guarantees integrability wrt all measurable relatively compact set (use definition with characteristic function). The reverse is simpler as set of compact sets is smaller than the set of measurable rel.compact sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the discussion in comments and simplification.

Compact sets form the set $\mathscr{K} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(T)$ the with property:

1. $A\cup B\in\mathscr{K},$ given $A,B \in\mathscr{K}$

Construct a minimal clan $\mathscr{C} \supseteq \mathscr{K}$ starting with elements of $\mathscr{K}$ and applying finite number of steps:

1. $A\cup B\in\mathscr{C},$ given $A,B \in\mathscr{C}$
2. $A\setminus B\in\mathscr{C},$ given $A,B \in\mathscr{C}$

> If $\boldsymbol f$ is locally integrable wrt $\mathscr{C},$ then it is trivially locally integrable wrt $\mathscr{K}.$

> **$\mu$ is Radon measure.** This is the case for Lebesgue measure. Under this assumption:
>
> 1. Elements of $\mathscr{C}$ are $\mu$-integrable. For $\phi_K, K\in\mathscr{K}$ this is the property of Radon measure.
> 2. If $\boldsymbol f$ is locally integrable wrt $\mathscr{K},$ then it is locally integrable wrt $\mathscr{C}:$

1. take $C\in\mathscr{C},$ it is constructed in finite steps from elements of $\mathscr{K}.$ If one step was used, done.
2. Otherwise, $C=C'\cup C'',$ or $C=C'\setminus C''$ and constructions of $C', C''\in\mathscr{C}$ involve fewer steps, use induction hypothesis and formulas:
   $$\phi_{C\cup C'} = \phi_{C} +\phi_{C'} -\phi_{C}\phi_{C'},$$ $$\phi_{C\setminus C'} = \phi_{C} -\phi_{C}\phi_{C'}$$
   "$|\boldsymbol f\phi_C|, |\boldsymbol f\phi_{C'}|$ are $\mu$-integrable ($\mu$-measurable + upper integral is finite)" implies
   $$|\boldsymbol f\phi_C\phi_{C'}| = 
     \sqrt{|\boldsymbol f\phi_C|}\sqrt{|\boldsymbol f\phi_{C'}|} =
     |\boldsymbol f\phi_C||\phi_{C'}|
   $$
   is $\mu$-measurable (product of measurable functions, first equality) and upper integral is finite (second equality).

Additional comments:

1. $\mathscr{C}$ consists of relatively compact sets, trivially;
2. Under the same assumption about $\mu,$ one can construct another equivalent clan containing only relatively compact sets:
   $$
    \mathscr{C}_1 =
     \{C\in \mathscr{P}(T): \phi_C \text{ is } \mu\text{-measurable and }
       C\subseteq K, \text{ for some }K\in\mathscr{K}\}
   $$
3. Locally integrable function in the case of Lebesgue measure, assumed that $\boldsymbol f$ is measurable from the start. This is redundant if one assumes $\boldsymbol f \phi_K$ is measurable for each $K\in \mathscr{K}:$ these function are even integrable and local measurability is equivalent to measurability.
4. I wanted to be on safer side and assumed that $\mu$ is Radon. I think this assumption can be dropped. Claim "$C\in \mathscr{C}$ are integrable" and claim about $\mathscr{C}_1$ become false.

Comment: More accurately, one needs to prove the if $\boldsymbol h, \boldsymbol g$ are measurable functions, then
$$
  (\boldsymbol h/ \boldsymbol g)(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    \boldsymbol h(x)/\boldsymbol g(x), &\boldsymbol g(x) \neq 0\\
    c, &\boldsymbol g(x) = 0
  \end{cases}
$$
is measurable for any $c\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\},$ assuming $0 \cdot \pm\infty = 0.$ And then consider $\boldsymbol h = \boldsymbol f\phi_C, \boldsymbol g = \sqrt{|\boldsymbol f|\phi_{C'}}.$

Answer (score 2):

The way the notion of locally integrable function is given in the OP seems to depend on the ring (clan); also, it seems to be too broad.
For example, consider  $(\mathbb{R},\overline{\mathcal{B}}^\lambda(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure on the real line and $\overline{\mathcal{B}}^\lambda(\mathbb{R})$ is the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $\lambda$. The family $\mathcal{C}_f$ of finite subsets  $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring (clan) of measurable set, and according to the definition in the OP, any real-extended valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ is locally integrable. The space of all real-extended functions is not very useful or interest from the point of view of Lebesgue integration (or Bochner's itegration) however. From this one sees that:

- Some rings are more useful (or meaningful) than others, and that one should talk about $\mathcal{C}$-locally integrable functions in $(T,\mathcal{F},\mu)$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a ring.
- To yield an interesting family of locally integrable functions, a  ring should have additional properties related to the underlying space $(T,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. The minimal requirements should probably be that $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{F}$ and that $\mu(C)<\infty$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$. Still, these simple properties are too broad.

For example, in a locally compact Hausdorff space $T$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, the set $\mathcal{K}_{rc}$ of all relatively compact sets form a ring. Furthermore, due to the Riesz-representation theorem (if one follows the ways of Lebesgue-Charatheodory) or the Daniell-Stone theorem (following the ways of Daniell), the ring $\mathcal{K}_{rc}$ is a determining class for the collection of Radon measures (measures associated to linear functionals on $\mathcal{C}_c(T)$), that is if two Radon measures coincide on $\mathcal{K}_{rc}$, then the measures are the same.

Comment: Integrability for extended functions does not always permit exceptional values for integral. This is not a case in Bourbaki's exposition (integrable functions are allowed to have only finite values) and local integrability of extended measurable functions is not trivial.

Comment: @dsh: What is your point relative to my posting?

Comment: Deleted shorter version of comment. If ring of finite sets is used, then any function is locally integrable, if ring contains all compact and/or all open relatively sets, then not all measurable functions with extended values are locally integrable and it makes sense to consider them from the point of view of local integrability. I do not agree with "The space of all real-extended functions is not very useful or interest from the point of view of Lebesgue integration (or Bochner's itegration) however."

Comment: @dsh: Notice that even functions that are not $\mu$-measurable are integrable relative to the  the clan of  finite sets; those functions are not interesting for integration. That is what I said isn my posting  "... the space of all real-extended functions ..." the key is the determining pronoun "all". Of course, $\mu$-measurable functions with values in $\overline{R}$ are of interest.

Answer (score 0):

here is my try
i think that that if we want to show the given definition of locally integrable functions with respect to a measure $\mu$ reduces to the standard definition in the case of a finite-dimensional vector space or a more general topological vector space, we need to carefully analyze the conditions and assumptions involved in both definitions.

Let's denote the standard definition of locally integrable functions on a topological space $T$ with respect to a measure $\mu$ as Definition 2. For the purpose of clarity, let's state Definition 2:

**Definition 2** (Standard Definition): A function $f$ on a topological space $T$ is said to be locally integrable with respect to a measure $\mu$ if, for every compact subset $K$ of $T$, there exists a $\mu$-integrable function $g_K$ such that $f$ coincides with $g_K$ almost everywhere on $K$.

Now, let's establish the connection between Definition 1 and Definition 2 in the context of a finite-dimensional vector space or a topological vector space.

1. **Finite-Dimensional Vector Space:**

   - In a finite-dimensional vector space, every  closed bounded subset is compact. This is a consequence of the Heine-Borel theorem, which states that in Euclidean spaces, a subset is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.
   - Considering that every subset is compact, Definition 1, which involves the local integrability over sets in a clan $\mathscr C$, is essentially equivalent to requiring integrability over every compact subset.
   - Therefore, in the finite-dimensional case, Definition 1 reduces to Definition 2, as every set in the clan is compact.
2. **Topological Vector Space:**

   - In a more general topological vector space, we need to consider the topology of the space and the properties of the clan $\mathscr C$.
   - Definition 1 involves the clan $\mathscr C$, which needs to satisfy certain properties. If $\mathscr C$ is chosen in such a way that it includes compact sets or satisfies conditions equivalent to local compactness, then Definition 1 reduces to Definition 2.
   - The topology of the topological vector space plays a crucial role in determining the properties of the clan $\mathscr C$ that would lead to equivalence with Definition 2.

when $T$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, or when the topological vector space has certain properties such as local compactness, Definition 1 reduces to the standard definition of locally integrable functions (Definition 2). The key lies in understanding the relationship between the clan $\mathscr C$ and the compact subsets of the space, which ensures that local integrability over sets in $\mathscr C$ is equivalent to local integrability over compact subsets.

Comment: "In a finite-dimensional vector space, every subset is compact" should be "In a finite-dimensional vector space, every **closed bounded** subset is compact". Compact sets does not form a clan: $A\setminus B$ is not compact if $A$ and $B$ are compact, because $A\setminus B$ is not closed.

Comment: thanks for pointing out i will edit

Comment: As @dsh pointed out, compact sets do not form a clan in finite nor infinite dimensional topological spaces. This is one of the difficulties I've found in my personal analysis of the problem. Moreover the second point in your analysis for finite dimensional spaces says: "Considering the every subset is compact,..." is not true.

Comment: Furthermore your analysis of the infinite dimensional topological space case seems to be simply a rephrasing of other comments and observations. It clear  that the essence of the solution to the posed problem consist in choosing a clan $\mathscr C$ in such a way this implies integrability on every compact set, but your analysis does not say how to practically proceed in doing so.